# Finding Most instances of a month

Tags: sql, oracle, count

So this is pretty much the table (already narrowed down the desired columns)

**DATEREGIS**:

```
10-AUG-95 
02-MAY-01
12-NOV-98
09-OCT-99
12-NOV-98
2-NOV-00
12-AUG-01
```

and what I am trying to do is create a query to find the busiest month.

This is what I have right now but its all kinds of wrong, and i can;t for the life of me figure this one out.

```
SELECT 
    dateregistered, count(dateregistered) as count
FROM 
    pet
HAVING 
    count = MAX(count)
GROUP BY 
    dateregistered;
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

EDIT* The DBMS is SQL*Plus

Comment: *SQL Plus* is **not** a database - it's a developer's tool for **Oracle** (which is the actual **database system** here ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by month and count. Order by count descending and select the first row from this list.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT to_char(dateregistered,'mm') as month, count(*) as cnt
  FROM pet
  GROUP BY to_char(dateregistered,'mm')
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Month,max(count)
from 
(
SELECT datepart(mm,dateregistered) Month, count(*) as count
FROM pet
Group by datepart(mm,dateregistered);
)t
group by Month
```

Comment: This is what i got:ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> SP2-0042: unknown command ")t" - rest of line ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer in this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to learn more of mysql functions.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(dateregistered), count(dateregistered) as count
FROM `pet` 
group by MONTH(dateregistered)
order by MONTH(dateregistered) desc
```